# Вывод форматированного текста

Tags: html, groovy, grails

Есть HTML код в базе. Как его правильно разместить в документе, сохраняя ранее заготовленное форматирование?

Допустим, есть текст:

```
< span style="font-weight: bold;">Лопата< /span>
```

Его нужно вывести соблюдая правила форматирования, в этом случае просто жирным.

Как это сделать? Вывожу из БД на страницу все вперемешку. JS не использую, все встроенными средствами Grails.

Comment: Если php то регулярные выражения вам в помощь. А лучше организуйте bb-коды, информации в интернете масса. Да и это значительно упростит вам работу.

Comment: Нет, не пхп, а про bb-коды дайте, пожалуйста, точнее наводку.

Comment: Все, проблема решена. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337464/overriding-grails-views-default-codec-html-config-back-to-none

John Flinchbaugh порешал.